# Insert a character entity on .click() with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, insert, entity, character

I'd like to insert the character entity ✓ (`&#10003;`) at the end of a list item after an href has been clicked:

```
<a href="" id="answer1">Click here to answer</a>

<ul>
<li>Answer 1</li>
</ul>

$("#answer1").click(function(){
// Add &#10003; to the end of the list item, such as: "<li>Answer 1 &#10003;</li>"
});
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how much li elements you have, but for this html as you shown

```
$("#answer1").click(function(){
    $('ul li').append('&#10003;');
});
```

Comment: But this will append ''&#10003;' to all the li's.. Oh well, its accepted.

Comment: I have written that this for his html only(as shown in question). Probably he has only one ul and li.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
$("#answer1").click(function(){
   $(this).html() += $(this).html() + '&#10003'; // just format the Html anyway you want
});
```

**Edit**

I mis-read your question.

for your UL ie... its something like

```
<ul>
   <li>Answer 1</li>
   <li>Answer 2</li>
   <li>Answer 3</li>
</ul>
```

then your Html to show the answers - perhaps store the answers index:

```
<a href="" class="anwers" data-answer="0">Click here to answer</a>
```

in your javascript

```
$("a.answers").click(function(){
   // get the answer index
   var i = $(this).attr("data-answer");

   var answer = $("ul > li:eq(" + i + ")");
   answer.html( answer.html() + '&#10003' );
 });
```